# Handle user login using asymmetric cryptography

Tags: authentication, cryptography, passwords

Is it possible to implement a login protocol with asymetric cryptography instead of the hashed password method?

For example, while creating an account, the client generates a private/public key pair from a hash of the username and password. The public key is then sent to the server with the username, and the server stores the username and the public key. When the user wants to login, he enters his password, the client regenerates the private key, signs a nonce with it, and sends the signed message to the server. The server is then able to authenticate the user as he knows the public key associated with the username.

Is there any flaws in this protocol?

And what would be the advantages over storing the password hash?

Comment: It seems secure if the connection to the server is already secured for example with TLS. Nevertheless, since this is not directly related to programming, it's better suited for [security.se]

Comment: I don't even see the need for the website to be TLS protected with this protocol. The only things that could be sniffed is the public key which is public and the signed message, which can also be public.

Comment: It's still vulnerable against a man-in-the-middle attacker without verifying the public key of the server (trust root).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a serious flaw with the authentication, yes, depending on the implementation. If Bob is the server and Alice is the client, with Mallory a malicious eavesdropper:

If Alice generates a random number, concatenates this with her username, encrypts with her private key and sends to server. Server decrypts and verifies with Alice's public key. Without the server saving the random number, this is susceptible to replay attacks - Mallory could just listen in, save the blocks that Alice sends to the server and just replay them later. Without saving them, the server would be none the wiser.

To protect the server against this, the server would have to generate the random number. It would also need to be a secure random number, otherwise Mallory could predict, or at least guess what the next number will be.

If Mallory could intercept messages, then he can purport to be Alice - he intercepts all communications and just relays them, even if the server generates the random number.

Alice and Bob both need to be able to prove that it was the other who has cheated. They also need to be able to detect tampering from Mallory - the protocol needs some extra layers to ensure authenticity of the messages.

There is research going into this at the moment, but as far as I know, it is very difficult to authenticate a user without a trusted certificate authority also being used: public keys can be known by all, but any attacker can swap their own public key for that of another without detection, unless there is trust established through a certificate authority.